# Creating Single Page HTML carosel panels with Razor CSHTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, carousel

I'm trying to create a View within MVC4, that has a sort of set of carousel buttons at the bottom of a container class box. I want to be able to click on those buttons to switch between content without leaving the view index page.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGv70.png)

When I press each button I want to be able to see new HTML paragraphs passed to the render frame.

The panel css is defined in the shared "_MainLayout.cshtml." but I want to have content render based on which panel is selected

```
@if (Page.SelectedPanel == 1){
                    @page1
                }
                else if (Page.SelectedPanel == 2){
                    @page2
                )
```

Are there any good related examples or tutorials like this anywhere? I can't seem to find anything. I'm pretty new to MVC, but some web API background with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it in different ways, either using JavaScript or having in your controller a method which return different partial views based on your selected panel value.

Personnaly I would choose the JavaScript solution since it avoids multiple client server calls.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

- if the paragraphs are not very long, the easier way is to render all the page content, hiding all but he initial paragraphs (to do this, in the view moel, appart from the paragraps , you should include a parameter indicating if it's vissible or hidden, to render each instance appropriately). Then when the user "moves" the carousel, change the visible paragraph using JavaScript.
- if the content in the paragraphs is dynamic, or too complex, you can use Ajax. When rendering the page, render only the carousel and the first view. Then, when the user "moves" the carousel, load the correspondign content invoking the partial action using ajax.

NOTE: if you google "mvc ajax partial view" you'll find a lot of examples on how to do render the partial view with ajax. You can include "unobtrusive" in your google query to see a different, more automatic technique.

For the client side, you can use for example this jquery plugin: [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/). You can change the visible paragraph (or load it using ajax) on its [targetin event](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/events.html#targetin).